# Left join one table with itself

Tags: php, mysql, left-join

```
SELECT s1.receiverID, s2.senderID
FROM messages as s1
LEFT JOIN messages as s2 ON s1.receiverID = s2.senderID
```

I want to combine "messages" table where the senderID and receiverID are the same to achieve something like conversation flow, but when i run this it returns 10,422 total rows.When the all rows is 3000 so how it returns more ?!

// Sample scenario: user with id = 8 goes to this url sample.com/inbox/user=275. And i want to show all messages between them to achieve something like conversation flow/chat.

Comment: Does adding `AND s1.pk > s2.pk` help? (Where `pk` is the primary key of the table.) What do sender/receiver ID represent? (Edit: Also, didn't see that you are using a left join, as Russell Davis has pointed out.)

Comment: Can you provide a simple example and the expected result?

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite a bit confused about users, urls and messages, now. Can you provide your minimal table structure, sample data and your expected result?

Comment: id,receiverID,senderID,message,status thats it as for the expected result it depends how much are the messages between two users. We have user A and user B and i want to return all messages between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example could help you figure out why you get more rows after the join.

```
rID sID
1   2
1   3
2   1
3   1

s1.rID s1.sID s2.rID s2.sID
1      2      2      1
1      2      3      1
1      3      2      1
1      3      3      1
2      1      1      2
3      1      1      3
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't want a join.  you just want to get all the messages that have both users as sender and receiver.

```
select * -- (or whatever)
from messages
where
(senderid = [userId] and receiverid = [otherUserId])
or (senderid = [otherUserId] and receiverid = [userId])
```

the join as you have written it is saying "give me every combination of messages in the system where the sender of one message is the same as the receiver of another and if there is anyone that has received a message but not sent any, show me those too with nulls for the values for sender."

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you're actually looking for?

```
select t1.senderID as t1senderID, t1.receiverID as t1receiverID,
  t2.senderID as t2senderID, t2.receiverID as t2receiverID
from messages t1
join messages t2
on t1.senderID = t2.receiverID and t1.receiverID = t2.senderID
```

Sample date would help a lot.

**Edit:**

Given this comment:

> We have user A and user B and i want to return all messages between them

You're looking for this:

```
select * from t1
where (senderID = 'A' and receiverID = 'B') or
      (senderID = 'B' and receiverID = 'A')
```

Comment: Sample scenario: user with id = 8 goes to this url http://sample.com/inbox/user=275. And i want to show all messages between them to achieve something like conversation flow/chat.

Comment: @MarianPetrov: Remember to accept this answer if it has solved the issue (I noticed you haven't accepted any answer yet)